# Instance variable from Rails model: undefined method `any?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to display some affiliate products while keeping my controllers as skinny as possible. But does anybody know why this isn't working?

```
undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
```

**app/models/shopsense.rb**

```
require "rest_client"

module Shopsense
  def self.fetch
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      :method => :get,
      :url => "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&fts=women&offset=0&limit=10"
    )

    # !!! ATTENTION !!!
    #
    # It works if I put the below in `shopsense` in the controller instead
    #

    @products = JSON.parse(response)["products"].map do |product|
      product = OpenStruct.new(product)
      product
    end
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/main_controller.rb**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  before_action :shopsense

  def index
  end

  def shopsense
    Shopsense.fetch
  end
end
```

**app/views/main/index.html.erb**

```
<% if @products.any? %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="product">
      <%= link_to product.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index.html.erb is requesting an instance variable @products, which isn't available through in the index action of your controller.

Put the instance variable in your index action:

```
def index
  @products = Shopsense.fetch
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables don't belong in a model. So you can not use `@products` there. Put it back into the controller and you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Correct - instance variables in rails declared in the controller are available in the view. In your case, you are declaring the instance variable inside a module, and not the controller.

Try this:

`def index
   @products = shopsense
end`

In this case, your controller will pass on the `@products` instance variable to the view

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately klausinho's answer came 30 seconds before yours.

Answer (score 1):

Because @products should be a member of MainController to be visible inside the view.

This should work:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  before_action :shopsense

  ...

  def shopsense
    @products = Shopsense.fetch
  end
end
```

Another option is to include the Shopsense module into MainController:

```
module Shopsense
  def fetch
      ...
  end
end

class MainController < ApplicationController
  include Shopsense

  before_action :fetch

  ...
end
```